Azure keyword recognition model (`.table`) not working when feeding it wave files
I have the following script:
import time
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import logging

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# The phrase your keyword recognition model triggers on.
KEYWORD = "KEYWORD"


def recognize_keyword_from_wav_file(wav_file_path):
    """Performs keyword-triggered speech recognition with a WAV file."""
    global true_positives, false_positives, false_negatives

    try:
        speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription='xyz', region='westeurope')
        model = speechsdk.KeywordRecognitionModel("./keyword.table")
        audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=wav_file_path)
        speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to initialize speech recognizer: {e}")
        return

    def recognizing_cb(evt):
        """Callback for recognizing event."""
        
        try:
            if evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizingKeyword:
                logging.info(f'RECOGNIZING KEYWORD: {evt}')
            elif evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech:
                logging.info(f'RECOGNIZING: {evt}')
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error in recognizing callback: {e}")

    def recognized_cb(evt):
        """Callback for recognized event."""
        
        try:
            if evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedKeyword:
                logging.info(f'RECOGNIZED KEYWORD: {evt}')
            elif evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
                logging.info(f'RECOGNIZED: {evt}')
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error in recognized callback: {e}")

    try:
        speech_recognizer.recognizing.connect(recognizing_cb)
        speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(recognized_cb)
        speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: logging.info(f'SESSION STARTED: {evt}'))
        speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: logging.info(f'SESSION STOPPED {evt}'))
        speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: logging.info(f'CANCELED {evt}'))

        speech_recognizer.start_keyword_recognition(model)
        logging.info(f'Say something starting with "{KEYWORD}" followed by whatever you want...')

        speech_recognizer.recognize_once()

        speech_recognizer.stop_keyword_recognition()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error during speech recognition: {e}")


# Example usage:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    wav_file_path = "./output01.wav"
    recognize_keyword_from_wav_file(wav_file_path)

This is only giving me RecognizedSpeech but never RecognizedKeyword. This happens when using wave files as input to the keyword recognition model instead of the default microphone streamed by: audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(use_default_microphone=True), which works fine. Any ideas?

I updated the recognizing_cb and recognized_cb  functions with evt.result.text to recognize the keyword. This successfully resolved the problem with the Azure keyword recognition model failing to detect keywords when WAV files were used as input.
Here is the updated line in your code.
logging.info(f'RECOGNIZING KEYWORD: {evt.result.text}') 

Below is the complete modified code:
import time
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
KEYWORD = "KEYWORD"

def recognize_keyword_from_wav_file(wav_file_path):
    """Performs keyword-triggered speech recognition with a WAV file."""
    try:
        speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription='<speech_key>', region='<speech_region>')
        model = speechsdk.KeywordRecognitionModel("path/to/.table")
        
        audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=wav_file_path)
        speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to initialize speech recognizer: {e}")
        return

    def recognizing_cb(evt):
        """Callback for recognizing event."""
        try:
            if evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizingKeyword:
                logging.info(f'RECOGNIZING KEYWORD: {evt.result.text}')
            elif evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech:
                logging.info(f'RECOGNIZING: {evt.result.text}')
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error in recognizing callback: {e}")

    def recognized_cb(evt):
        """Callback for recognized event."""
        try:
            if evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedKeyword:
                logging.info(f'RECOGNIZED KEYWORD: {evt.result.text}')
            elif evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
                logging.info(f'RECOGNIZED: {evt.result.text}')
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error in recognized callback: {e}")

    try:
        speech_recognizer.recognizing.connect(recognizing_cb)
        speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(recognized_cb)
        speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: logging.info(f'SESSION STARTED: {evt}'))
        speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: logging.info(f'SESSION STOPPED {evt}'))
        speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: logging.info(f'CANCELED {evt}'))

        speech_recognizer.start_keyword_recognition(model)
        logging.info(f'Say something starting with "{KEYWORD}" whatever you want.')
        result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once()

        if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
            logging.info(f"No speech could be recognized: {result.no_match_details}")
        elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
            cancellation_details = result.cancellation_details
            logging.info(f"Speech Recognition canceled: {cancellation_details.reason}")
            if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
                logging.error(f"Error details: {cancellation_details.error_details}")

        speech_recognizer.stop_keyword_recognition()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error during speech recognition: {e}")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    wav_file_path = "path/to/.wav"
    recognize_keyword_from_wav_file(wav_file_path)

Output :
The following code ran successfully as below.


If your keyword was part of the sentence in the .wav, you should see RECOGNIZED KEYWORD... right? I cannot see it in your output
